# Abbreviate numbers with with varying precision

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal, abbreviation

I've done numerous attempts to get this to work. But everything i've found so has ended up in either wrong rounding of the numbers - or hits a wall with the abbreviated character.

What i want is a function which i can give a single number, say like `1234`, and it should shorten it to: `1.23k`. But the precision can vary depending on how big the number is.

So my question is, how do i write such a function?

```
expected outcomes:
1 -> 1
9 -> 9
10 -> 10
100 -> 100
999 -> 999
1000 -> 1k
1001 -> 1k
1010 -> 1.01k
10100 -> 10.1k
1000000 -> 1m
1010000 -> 1.01m
10000000 -> 10m
1000000000000000 -> 1quad
1000000000000000000 -> 1quint
```

So the suffix is not alway single letters, they can be whole words.

Is this possible to do dynamically? or do i have to hardcode every single outcome?

Comment: You are not giving enough details about your task. Think it through and tell us what display types you have and which would be used under what criteria.

Comment: Search for "humanizing" libraries. There are a few good ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you gave, I came up with [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/aymericbeaumet/zb5hqx83/). It is based on the [`Number.prototype.toExponential`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) method.

Example:

```
console.log(abbreviate(1000000000000000000)); // 1quint
```

You will have to tweak it though, so that it matches your need concerning rounding.

Comment: This worked with some minor teaks.

This is the version i currently use:

https://www.diffchecker.com/vr1evn9e

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a JS library, [approximate-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/approximate-number), that does something pretty close to what you're looking for. Specifying `precision: 3` would get everything on your list except for the last couple, because it currently only goes up to trillions for suffixes. (JS's max safe integer is 9,007t).

I suppose I could be tweaked to go further - the max safe integer doesn't really matter when you're approximating anyways.